# Получение высокоинтеллектуального удовольствия [Как это слово называется]

Tags: терминология

Собственно из заглавия и вытекает вопрос.

Пример: После просмотра фильма я [испытал/получил, если необходимо] (искомое слово)

Наслаждение ? - слишком объёмно. Удовлетворение ? - ещё дальше. Гедонизм ? - то же самое, что и первое, несмотря на то что более подходящее в контексте вопроса, хотя не в точку.

Быть может, кто-нибудь подскажет?

Comment: А почему бы Вам так и не сказать: "Получил интеллектуальное наслаждение"?

Comment: Хочется выражаться более лаконично.

Comment: Кстати, если фильм произвел на вас сильное эмоциональное воздействие, можно сказать "испытал эстетическое наслаждение", если же фильм поразил только революционными идеями, приемами - формулировка "испытал интеллектуальное наслаждение" будет лучше описывать Ваше впечатление от просмотра.

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта, но талант не в краткости состоит.

Comment: И тем более не в словоблудии. :)

Comment: По словам Чернышевского, «художественность состоит в том, чтобы каждое слово было не только у места, — чтобы оно было необходимо, неизбежно и чтоб как можно было меньше слов».

Answer (score 2):

А-а-а! Я поняла, что Вам нужно, дорогой Вы наш ценитель краткости, - "катарсис"!

Comment: :) Уверяю, его уже испытывал, как оказалось. А ранее полагал, что катарсис - высвобождение негативных эмоций/чувств, посредством их "выплеска" на окружающих. Учимся понемногу, учимся..

Answer (score 1):

Фильм вызвал во мне  чувство  духовного и эстетического   удовольствия.

Можно еще: чувство гармонической приятности, но тогда это будет единственный вариант в Нацкорпусе.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в такой ситуации сказала: "Получила эстетическое наслаждение". Есть еще выражение "бальзам на душу", когда содержание книги/фильма совпадает с Вашим мировоззрением. Ну, еще "наслаждалась каждой строчкой". А вообще, думаю, если из контекста понятно, что речь идет о книге или фильме (пьесе, картине и т.д.), то и так ясно, что удовольствие от них может быть только интеллектуальным, духовным и эстетическим.

Answer (score 0):

ЧТО-ТО испытывают в процессе.Получается, во время фильма ничего не испытывал, а после просмотра дошло) Можно сказать: "Я смотрел и наслаждался". Или просто: "Фильм мне очень понравился"